# react-beautiful-dnd - weird styles appear when dragging and element

Tags: reactjs, react-beautiful-dnd

Using the `react-beautiful-dnd` library, While dragging an element (before dropping it) a weird black point appears on my column.

eg:

Answer (score 1):

This is because when you are dragging an element, the `{provided.placeholder}` gets active and then an element is inserted on the DOM, this element could be a "li", a "div" etc.. according to your markup.

```
<Droppable droppableId="droppable-1">
  {(provided, snapshot) => (
  <div ref={provided.innerRef} {...provided.droppableProps}>
     <li>
       My element
     </li>
    {provided.placeholder}
 </div>

  )}
</Droppable>
```

**So the solution is you need to style (or remove the styles) that are affecting the automatically inserted element.**

Probably a CSS class like:

```
li {
    list-style: none;
}
```

Will remove the black point because it will affect the `{provided.placeholder}` element (in case it's a "li").